# flask api crash after second post

Tags: python, json, flask

Sorry for my vocabulary and poor knowledge this is my first python project.
So I’ve create api in flask which should response with 2 plot pictures  on every post.
api is working great but only for first post, every time when second post is send flask throw below error:

```
[2021-02-17 01:02:33,438] ERROR in app: Exception on /postjson [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\wtasarek\Documents\study\iss\URA_python\restApi.py", line 62, in postJsonHandler
    plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 1142, in subplot
    ax = fig.add_subplot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1393, in add_subplot
    self.sca(ax)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 2070, in sca
    self._axobservers.process("_axes_change_event", self)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 229, in process
    self.exception_handler(exc)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 81, in _exception_printer
    raise exc
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 224, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 2167, in <lambda>
    self._axobservers.connect("_axes_change_event", lambda arg: func(arg))
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2712, in notify_axes_change
    self.toolbar.update()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 3276, in update
    self.set_history_buttons()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 667, in set_history_buttons
    self._buttons['Back']['state'] = state_map[can_back]
  File "C:\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1649, in __setitem__
    self.configure({key: value})
  File "C:\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1638, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1628, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Feb/2021 01:02:33] "POST /postjson HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Python code:

```py
@app.route('/postjson', methods=['POST'])
def postJsonHandler():
    print(request.is_json)
    content = request.get_json()
    print(content)

   ... //some python code which return plots


    with BytesIO() as output:
        plt.savefig(output, transparent=True, format="PNG")
        contents = output.getvalue()

    plot1_base64 = base64.b64encode(contents)

    plot2 = plt.figure(2)
    plt.plot(simulator_inst.qr[:, 0], simulator_inst.qr[:, 1], 'b')
    plt.plot(simulator_inst.x, simulator_inst.y, 'r')

    with BytesIO() as output:
        plt.savefig(output, transparent=True, format="PNG")
        contents = output.getvalue()

    plot2_base64 = base64.b64encode(contents)

  
    print(str(plot2_base64, 'utf-8'))

    data_dict = {'plot1': str(plot1_base64, 'utf-8'),
                 'plot2': str(plot2_base64, 'utf-8'),
                 }

    data_json = json.dumps(data_dict)

    return data_json
```

I spend few hours on searching for a possible solution, and I’m stacked.
I’m bagging for help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like your error is in tkinter, not flask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bit from your stack trace is telling:

```python
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 667, in set_history_buttons
    self._buttons['Back']['state'] = state_map[can_back]
```

This means you're using the tkinter GUI backend for matplotlib.  Generally this doesn't work well with any library that uses threads, like Flask does.  The easist path is generally to use one of the non-GUI backends for matplotlib.  Simply putting this at the top of your script will instruct matplotlib to use it's "agg" backend

```python
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

This will force it to use a non-GUI backend, which should prevent the threading issues you're seeing.